TYPO3 weird redirect to FIRST_INSTALL wizard after mistake
I have a local composer installation of TYPO3 v11.5.38 and this install was working since weeks. Yesterday I changed something in packages/myextension/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php. I just wanted to change some BE labels but I did a small mistake. After clearing cache and reloading the BE (I was successfully logged in) TYPO3 started redirecting me to the first install wizard and I cannot stop it. Whenever I call the FE or BE now, I get redirected to the first install wizard.
How can I prevent this? I think my mistake in tt_content.php leads TYPO3 to write some wrong information to "somewhere", but I cleared the cache files manually (htdocs/var/cache/*)
Why does TYPO3 think it needs to be installed freshly?

What kind of mistake did you do? IMO there is no mistake you could make in the TCA config, that leads to such behaviar.

I would first remove /htdocs/var and /htdocs/vendor and do a composer update.

It was a small typo while changing the label of an extension in 'showitem' in tt_content's TCA config.
Removing /htdocs/var and /htdocs/vendor and composer update did not help.
It's really strange, all my WAMP vhosts still working, just the redirect to the FIRST_INSTALL wizard occurs in this local vhost.
IIRC there was a kind of typo3IsInstalled = true; variable somewhere or did I dream about it?

Ok, I reverted the project back to a state of some days ago and it seems to work again. I'll now first make a big cleanup and remove old (and obsolete) configs and stuff and run fresh updates of everything before I start changing the TCA config. Maybe there were some inconsistencies or obstacles in my way Thanks God there is something like GIT :-)

This problem appears when using composer reinstall $package, because the TYPO3 composer installer has a bug. Running composer dump fixes the problem.
